# Samba 4.1.17-Debian Access denied to fileshare

Tags: samba4

I freshly installed Debian 8 (Jessie) on a virtual machine. I installed the Samba 4.1.17 server with the intention to have shared folders on my network. I didn't change anything to the configuration, except that the following lines have been added to the end of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file:

```
[public]
comment = HTTPD public directory
read only = no
locking = no
path = /var/www
guest ok = no
```

I added my users with `smbpasswd` and made sure the users have 777 priviliges on the `/var/www` directory.

I can list the shares with `smbclient -L \\\\debian64-plankje` from both localhost as remotely from my old Debian 7 VM. (`debian64-plankje` is the hostname of the server)

If I set `guest ok = yes` then I can anonymously connect to the share with `smbclient \\\\debian64-public\\public`, but with `guest ok = no` set I get the error `tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`.

An extensive Google search didn't give me any hints to resolve this issue which I have trying to resolve for the last few hours. Just like with my old server I used the default configuration to which I only added above mentioned lined.

Below are the contents of my `smb.conf` file, hopefully you can help me figure out why I get the `NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED` error.

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
dns proxy = no

log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size = 1000
syslog = 0
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

server role = standalone server
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
unix password sync = yes
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
pam password change = yes
map to guest = bad user

[homes]
comment = Home Directories
browseable = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700
directory mask = 0700
valid users = %S

[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = no

[public]
comment = HTTPD public directory
read only = no
locking = no
path = /var/www
guest ok = no
```

Comment: You can increase the log level to 3 and check the log. How do you specify user name and password when connecting? Have you tried `WORKGROUP\user`?

Answer (score 1):

After checking the output of `smbtree -d3`, the following line caught my attention: `resolve_lmhosts: Attempting lmhosts lookup for name DEBIAN64-PLANKJ<0x20>`. It turns out that because my hostname is parsed as a NETBIOS name, I am bound to a limit of 15 characters. My original hostname `debian64-plankje` was 16. This resulted in some unexpected behavior of the Samba server where anonymous connects do succeed, but connects with credentials required don't.

Renaming the hostname of my server to `deb64-plankje` by editing `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts`, and rebooting afterwards (to ensure the new hostname was adopted) resolved the issue for me :).